# File on case no longer works by Case ID

Tags: civicase, activities

I've been testing CiviCRM 5.57.4 and noticed that I can no longer type in the Case ID when searching for the case to file an activity to. (I'm in Drupal 7) In version 5.45.7 it was still working. I verified that on dmaster it also does not work - I did create a case or two to test with since the sample data doesn't include cases.

[image: working on 5.45.7]

[image: not working dmaster 5.61]

I don't see any changes to the core file Case/Form/ActivityToCase.php that jump out at me as the cause. Does anyone know where else I could take a peek?

Comment: There's been lots of changes to entityref to support formbuilder et al. Possibly in there somewhere? I admit I haven't been following it too closely.

Comment: A couple candidates, including one which I, uh, merged, that are around the right timeframe: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24793, https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24976, https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24974

Comment: Ok it still works in 5.56, so it's not the one I merged. Phew!

Comment: In the meantime have created a ticket: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Fix is at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/25982

---

Git bisect says it is caused by https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24727/commits/f40da46a0dd2d7f8bdb5ed2ff3a453b527ebef94. I'll update the lab ticket.

Comment: This is wonderful, it fixes the issue. Thanks for creating the ticket AND solving it!